# C: Memory allocation - Is the following struct a naive workaround?

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-management, struct

I'm currently rolling my own split, trim and other utility string functions in C.
While rummaging about SO I've ascertained that functions like `strdup()` are, in
general, considered evil because it allocates memory (unlike other string functions
from the same library).

However, it seems inevitable that my functions can be written in such a way that they do not allocate memory. I'm trying to resolve this as best as I can. Currently, I've left all input
strings alone (const), and returned a pointer to a new string and documenting that the
return must later be free'd.

I'm pondering if there is a better way, and this idea struck me. I'm trying to figure out if it's actually a good idea or if it's a naive one. And therein lies my question, is the
following solution adviseable? If not, how come?

My idea is this, I'll create a struct like so:

```
typedef struct string {
    char *str;
    bool initialized;
} string;
```

using it for all my string manipulation work. At the end of all related functions, just
before the return statement I'll call another function, let's call it `destroy`, on the input string (which wouldn't be a char pointer but the aforementioned struct). That function in turn would check the boolean, `ìnitialized`, which denotes that
memory has been allocated and if so subsequently free it.

Comment: If, from an evaluation of the string functions, you get the feeling that `strdup()` is the one considered evil, you have been doing a strange evaluation.

Comment: `strdup()` isn't nearly as evil as `strcpy()`. The issue with `strcpy()` is that it can easily overwrite unallocated memory (thus corrupt the stack and allow for exploits in your software). People don't like `strdup()` because it breaks the `malloc`-`free` pattern, but it isn't considered evil. But you *need* to allocate strings, since you don't know how long the strings you need are going to be. Also, you don't really need to bother with all that. Just set the string to `NULL` ... that ensures that things like `free` and `realloc` just ignore it, and it stays much simpler than your struct.

Comment: I don't really get what your concern is. Could you please add a code example on what you try to solve with your struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typedef struct string {
    char *str;
    bool initialized;
} string;
```

> That function in turn would check the boolean, `ìnitialized`, which denotes that memory has been allocated and if so subsequently free it.

You do not need a struct to do that. Initialize with a null pointer any `char*` pointer that you could have wanted to use your struct for, and you can pass it to `free()` or `realloc()` without having to wonder whether or not it has been further assigned.

Comment: But then how do you use it to hold a pointer to a string constant?